# PAL consoles to US HDTV

Tags: ntsc, pal

what would be the best way to display a PAL TV signal on a modern HDTV in the USA?

Do HDMI upscalers do an acceptable job of getting PAL 50hz input out to a normal HDMI 1080p 60hz?

Comment: Many HDMI TVs accept 50Hz even in the United States because of globalised production. That doesn't answer the question but raises a follow-up query: are you sure you want a 60Hz output from the scaler?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: Yes, they all do (plus many US HDMI TVs accept 50 Hz anyway).

But you may want to check if they are able to process PAL input, as there are some (usually older) who don't. Also, there are differences in their upscaling algorithms, so while this is no big issue for a movie it might be annoying on certain consoles/games.

So it might help to try before buying if it's about a more expensive one. On the other hand, not much damage with the cheaper (<40USD) offers.

Comment: so if they do take pal input then the only challenge would be to ensure that there is adequate power (which is a nonissue with consoles that use a power brick).  the big question, i guess, is the output acceptable in terms of display, input lag, experience?

Comment: Power? Why? They always come with their own PS (unless using some special SCART plug models that use the VCRs PS).

Comment: I'd expect a 1080p screen to show PAL with better quality than NTSC, since 270 is a typical enough number of visible lines for a real analogue PAL set and is also an integral divider of 1080 — 1080/4 = 270. So you can scale up such that every original line is exactly the same height in the output. Whereas the idiomatic NTSC visible field height is more like 240, which suggests an awkward scaling of 4.5. That's why a lot of scalers prefer 720p output, as it's exactly triple 240. But I can't speak as to lag.